# Python Printing a Deque

Tags: python, arrays, queue, tostring, deque

I have an entire Deque Array class that looks like this:

```
from collections import deque
import ctypes

class dequeArray:

DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10  #moderate capacity for all new queues

def __init__(self):
    self.capacity = 5
    capacity = self.capacity
    self._data = self._make_array(self.capacity)
    self._size = 0
    self._front = 0

def __len__(self):
    return self._size

def __getitem__(self, k):   #Return element at index k
    if not 0 <= k < self._size:
        raise IndexError('invalid index')
    return self._data[k]

def isEmpty(self):
    if self._data == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def append(self, item):  #add an element to the back of the queue
    if self._size == self.capacity:
        self._data.pop(0)
    else:
        avail = (self._front + self._size) % len(self._data)
        self._data[avail] = item
        self._size += 1

#def _resize(self, c):
    #B = self._make_array(c)
    #for k in range(self._size):
        #B[k] = self._A[k]
    #self._data = B
    #self.capacity = capacity

def _make_array(self, c):
    capacity = self.capacity
    return (capacity * ctypes.py_object)()

def removeFirst(self):
    if self._size == self.capacity:
        self._data.pop(0)
    else:
        answer = self._data[self._front]
        self._data[self._front] = None
        self._front = (self._front + 1) % len(self._data)
        self._size -= 1
        print(answer)


def removeLast(self):
    return self._data.popleft()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self._data)
```

and when I try to print the deque in the main it prints out something like this,

```
<bound method dequeArray.__str__ of <__main__.dequeArray object at   0x1053aec88>>
```

when it should be printing the entire array. I think i need to use the **str** function and i tried adding

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self._data)
```

and that failed to give me the output. I also tried just

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(d)
```

d being the deque array but I still am not having any success. How do I do i get it to print correctly?

Comment: You are presumably trying to `print thing.__str__` instead of `thing.__str__()` (or just `str(thing)`).

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide the `class` definition

Comment: @Pynchia I added the rest of the class, i did not think it was of any use since I am just trying to figure out how to properly print the deque

Comment: it's incomplete, you have added the methods only. Your line `Deque Array class` leaves the door open to several possibilities. Please show what it inherits from

Comment: OK. I have never used `ctypes`: what does `self._data = (capacity * ctypes.py_object)()` do? Why is `deque` never used?

Comment: @Pynchia that is a line i am required to implement in order to allocate a block of memory

Comment: ``ctypes.py_object`` is killing a fly with a hammer.  Just use a list of objects.  But the real question is why you can't use ``collections.deque``.

Comment: @ArminRigo i know but i am required to use for this assignment. I just want to know how to properly print this deque

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should call the str function of each element of the array that is not NULL, can be done with the following str function:

```
def __str__(self):
    contents = ", ".join(map(str, self._data[:self._size]))
    return "dequeArray[{}]".format(contents)
```

Comment: `self._data[:self._size]` will raise an exception if you try to use it on uninitialized `ctypes` array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say, the above code does not raise an exception even if no elements have been added to the array.

Comment: Taking into consideration the way OP creates his `self._data` and pretending we're calling `__str__` right after the instantiation of the object, `self._data[:self._size]` can be reduced to the `(5 * ctypes.py_object)()[:5]` which throws `ValueError` at least on Python 3.5

Comment: right after the instantiation of the object `self._size = 0`

Comment: Ah, indeed, you're right. Then `q = dequeArray(); q.append(ctypes.py_object()); print(q)` will do the same, but this is definitely an extreme and unnatural case.

Answer (score 0):

What I get when I try to `q = dequeArray(); print(q)` is `<__main__.py_object_Array_5 object at 0x006188A0>` which makes sense. If you want it `list-like`, use something like this (`print` uses `__str__` method implicitly):

```
def __str__(self):
    values = []
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            values.append(self._data[i])
        except ValueError:  # since accessing ctypes array by index 
                            # prior to assignment to this index raises 
                            # the exception
            values.append('NULL (never used)')
    return repr(values)
```

---

Also, several things about the code:

```
from collections import deque
```

This import is never user and should be removed.

---

```
DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10
```

is never used. Consider using it in the `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, capacity=None):
    self.capacity = capacity or self.DEFAULT_CAPACITY
```

---

This variable inside `__init__` is never user and should be removed:

```
capacity = self.capacity
```

---

```
def _make_array(self, c):
    capacity = self.capacity
    return (capacity * ctypes.py_object)()
```

Though this is a valid code, you're doing it wrong unless you're absolutely required to do it in your assignment. Ctypes shouldn't be used like this, Python is a language with automated memory management. Just `return []` would be fine. And yes, variable `c` is never used and should be removed from the signature.

---

```
if self._data == 0
```

In `isEmpty` always evaluates to `False` because you're comparing `ctypes` object with zero, and `ctypes` object is definitely not a zero.

Comment: Thank you i will take into consideration